# list the longest collatz series in python

Tags: python

I am new at python and trying to solve the longest collatz series question. So I want to find out between 5 and 8, which number produce the longest collatz series and listed the series.

Here is my code, but now it is showing all series:

```
def collatz(n):
    collatzseq = 0
    
    while n != 1:
        print(n)
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = int(n/2)
        else:
            n = 3* n + 1
        collatzseq += 1    
    return collatzseq

maxleg = 0
maxvlu = 0

for i in range (5,8):
    collatzseq = collatz(i)
    
    if collatzseq > maxleg:
        maxleg = collatzseq
        maxvlu = i 

print(maxvlu, maxleg)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you confirm that the code is complete and that it functions correctly? If so, I recommend that you [edit] to add a summary of the testing (ideally as reproducible unit-test code).  If it's not working, it isn't ready for review (see [help/on-topic]) and the question may be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Python! For a newbie, your code is very good, but there's always ways to improve!

```
def collatz(n):
```

While it is not at all necessary in Python, type hints go a long way for someone trying to read your code. Try something like this:

```
def collatz(n:int) -> int:
```

```
    collatzseq = 0
    
    while n != 1:
```

The name `collatzseq` is not super descriptive, and it is generally good practice to seperate the words in your variables somehow. Some good alternatives might be `collatzLength`, `collatz_length` or even just `length`. Also, `while n != 1` will work fine for the inputs your thinking of, but if anyone comes along and tries to run it without reading it, they might put in a negative number and put your code into an infinite loop! Usually `while n > 1` is a better idea.

```
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = int(n/2)
        else:
            n = 3* n + 1
        collatzseq += 1
```

For the Collatz Conjecture, often people want their code to run as fast as possible. If that's the case, then replacing `n % 2 == 0` with simply `n % 2` isn't a bad idea. If you're not familiar, Python treats the number 0 like the boolean `False`, and every other number like `True`. So `n % 2` will be considered `True` for odd `n` and `False` for everything else. Also, it's generally best practice to use integer division, as opposed to dividing and using the `int()` fucntion (i.e. `n //= 2`).

Also! A quick tip in terms of the Collatz Conjecture specifically: performing the 3x + 1 operation on any odd number will give you an even number. I'll let you prove that yourself, but that means that you can speed up your code even more by not checking if the number is even or odd after performing the 3x + 1 operation.

```
maxleg = 0
maxvlu = 0
```

Again, not super clear variable names. Try `maxLength` and `maxValue` or `max_length` and `max_value`.

```
print(maxvlu, maxleg)
```

And finally your print statement. Once again, nothing wrong, just nit-picky stuff. It's generally nice to know what's being printed out. I personally like format strings, so something like `print(f'Maximum Value: {maxValue}, Maximum Collatz Length: {maxLength}')` is what I would write.

Over all, really good job- only minor fixes. I'd also reccomend adding some comments here and there to clear up any confusion for someone reading it. I'll put a complete code with all of the optimizations I talked about down below.

Keep learning Python!

```
# Define Function to Find Length of Collatz Sequence i
def collatz(n:int) -> int:
    
    length = 0
    while n > 1:
        print(n)

        # If n is Odd: n = 3n + 1
        if n % 2:
            n = 3 * n + 1
            length += 1

            print(n)
        
        # Otherwise: n = n/2
        n //= 2
        length += 1

    return length

maxValue = 0
maxLength = 0
for i in range(5, 8):
    # Get Length of Collatz Sequence i
    collatzLength = collatz(i)

    # If New Collatz Sequence is Longer than All Previous: Update Values
    if collatzLength > maxLength:
        maxLength = collatzLength
        maxValue = i

# Print Result
print(f'Maximum Value: {maxValue}, Maximum Collatz Length: {maxLength}')
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer - I hope to see more from you in future!

Answer (score 1):

## lint

Recommend you use
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black) or
[flake8](https://pypi.org/project/flake8)
to improve
[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008) readability.

## identifiers

They call it "code" for a reason.
One of the best ways to create source code that is like prose
is to carefully choose helpful identifiers.
You're trying to help the Gentle Reader understand your intent.

```
maxleg = 0
maxvlu = 0
```

Honestly, these are just terrible.
Nevermind that PEP-8 asks for `max_vlu` -- that would still be bad.
You apparently meant the following, so just *say* it:

```
max_length = 0
max_value = 0
```

This is a more sensible identifier, drawn from the problem domain:

```
    collatzseq = 0
```

I recommend changing it to just `length`.
My difficulty with calling it a "sequence" is
that's evocative of a "container", of the values
that `n` took on before arriving at one.

Also, you passed up an opportunity to label your results here:

```
print(maxvlu, maxleg)
```

As written, someone viewing the output would need to refer
to the source code to know how to interpret those figures.

## safety

Caller should have specified a positive input argument.
But what if he didn't?

```
    while n != 1:
```

What if he messed up and specified zero?
Yeah. That would be Bad. We loop forever.

Two ways to guard against such a mess-up are

1. `assert n >= 1` immediately upon entering the function
2. `while n > 1:`, to avoid infinite loop.

The first technique is called
[DbC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).
The second is
[defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

## integer division

Tiny nit: the `int(n/2)` assignment is more conveniently expressed
with the `//` [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions):

```
            n //= 2
```

## comments

There are no `"""docstrings"""` or `# comments`
in this codebase. I feel that is OK, as the code
is fairly simple and self explanatory.
Consider writing a one-sentence docstring
for future functions that you write.

Citing a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Statement_of_the_problem)
would be appropriate.

## type hints

It wouldn't hurt to throw in an optional type hint here:

```
def collatz(n: int):
```

While you're at it, may as well go all the way, even though
[mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy)
can easily deduce the return type.

```
def collatz(n: int) -> int:
```

Why?

1. It is useful advice to humans.
2. It can make IDE autocompletion work better.
3. It lets us do a `mypy` static analysis scan, which will sometimes reveal the bug you just wrote "for free".
4. It is essential setup for tacking on a `@jit` [numba](https://pypi.org/project/numba) decorator

## summary

This code achieves its design goals.

Producing quality software that others can read and understand
is not an easy thing, and you have started on such a journey.
I'm glad that you are soliciting critiques and seeking
to improve what you write.

Linting clean would make it a little easier for others to
read your work, and it costs you nothing.

The most important thing you could do is to "self review".
That is, when you're ready to commit and save a working program,
try to read it with fresh eyes. Come at it as if a stranger
had just walked up to the screen and started reading it for
the first time. Are the identifiers clear? Is the code
self explanatory? If not, consider a new variable name
or other refactoring.

Comment: I'd call the division issue more than a tiny nit about convenience. For example for n=34359738367, they get a wrong result because of that. Granted, they said they're interested in 5 to 8, but still. Talking about it but not talking about its danger is odd.

Comment: Ummm, pardon, @KellyBundy? I'm afraid I'm not quite following you yet. The example is `n = 2 ** 35 - 1`. When I ask cPython 3.10.8 to evaluate both ways it reports identical results of 17179869183, one less than `2 ** 34`. What is the "wrong result"? (Recall that python ints are a lot like scheme BigNums -- they will keep malloc'ing storage as their magnitude grows and grows.) I suppose that `@jit` numba behavior _would_ be very interesting!

Comment: I mean their `collatz(34359738367)` gives a wrong result, 454 instead of 529. Because of the division issue.

Comment: Yikes! Ok. Help me to understand how `int(n / 2)` behaves differently from `n // 2` in cPython? I guess we're calling a different function, truediv vs floordiv? Or maybe itruediv.

Comment: With `/`, you get a fixed-size `float`. Which means you lose precision at some point.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Right you are. All that lovely python integer machinery gets truncated down to 53 bits of mantissa! Thank you.

Comment: Yes. And while my 35 bits are quite a bit below 53, numbers n=(2^k)-1 grow a lot before they come down.

Comment: [Visualization](https://tio.run/##XY/RDoIwDEXf@YoaY8KEiDAVNNm3GNEqS5aCY8boz88xFIj3ocva07u75mWqmnjRaGsveIVzrdTJvENihwCcvvcW7yBg7Vu@PCupEAhmAtKe7NRoSSYkWEAWA61KaY4K6WaqkMVQSnK2bIDlFTwJwjmPHp0oSUQ2dy96uyQbl1C1@Mc6jC/dEUE6DCaxI5dwiK3RPDRNxkHQZ/79m2/4dp/zgu9yxqz9AA).